# CDI events not firing

Tags: java, gwt, errai

I have an Errai app which CDI events are not firing:

```
@Dependent
@Templated
@Page(path = "person")
public class PersonPage extends Composite {

    @Inject
    @Loaded
    Event<Person> loadedEvent;

    @PageShowing
    public void showing() {
        Browser.getWindow().getConsole().log("Firing event..."); // works fine
        loadedEvent.fire(new Person());
    }

    public void loaded(@Observes @Loaded Person person) {
        Window.alert("Fired");
    }

}
```

I think this code is pretty straightforward and I wonder why it is not firing.

Comment: Is the `showing` method actually called? Do you observe the event from a different (`@Singleton`) instance?

Comment: BTW, this Person object I am referring is a `@JsType(isNative = true, namespace = JsPackage.GLOBAL, name = "Object")`

Comment: Maybe the `@JsType` is interfering with the Event mechanism, did you try to wrap the `Person` class in a normal java class?

Comment: @k5_ not really since our models are JsInterop-based

Comment: Observer method must be in another bean, not in same bean which fires the event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your event is not being received because it is a native JS type. The issue is that Errai's `Event` implementation dispatches based on a `Class` object for that event type. This works for normal classes and even non-native JS types. But native JS types don't actually have classes at runtime; the compiler replaces any references with `JavaScriptObject.class`.

On the observer side, Errai generates code that registers observer methods based on the class name *that it figures out at compile time*.

Thus there is a mismatch, where even though it looks like your event is firing for `Person` events, it is really being dispatched for observers of `JavaScriptObject`.

Comment: Does it mean that there is no workaround for this scenario?

Comment: Wrapping `Person` in a Java class should work (e.g. `PersonEvent` or `PersonWrapper`). Not really nice but has the benefit of working.

Comment: For now, you'll have to wrap it as @k5_ suggested. Consider opening a JIRA issue for an enhancement to support this use case. It's possible we could support firing native JS types in a future release.

Comment: @k5_ thanks your suggestion worked. If you like you can make it an answer here.